# trim val checked how to check if a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I was wondering how I can check if a checkbox has been checked or not. I had this answer before but I do not know where I placed it. Here is the code:

```
if ($("#fileDir").is(":checked")) {
validation = "false";
} else {
values['fileDir'] = $.trim($("#fileDir").val());
}
```

Was it that was that you check if the checkbox had been checked?

Comment: What's the problem with the new code you've changed it to?

Comment: `values['fileDir'] = $("#fileDir").val();` that should be the values but it looks like its not working right

Comment: The value it will be is the one value you have set on the <input type="checkbox" id="fileDir" value="this">

Answer (score 1):

```
var checked = $('#fileDir').is(':checked');
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers - give a little explanation to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#fileDir").is(":checked")) {
    validation = false;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers - give a little explanation to go with it.

Comment: Hello how can I add my vaues !!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#fileDir").is(":checked")) {
  validation = "false";
}
```

There are a few ways of doing this, but this one is the best and is the most understandable

Comment: Now I'm having difficulty understanding the question - I'm guessing English isn't your mother tongue. I've answered what you asked in the title and the code that you gave beforehand. If you are asking a completely different question, make a new question.

Comment: I dispute using the string "false" is the best and most understandable method.

Comment: @AsksAnyway It's what the OP had it as originally - I didn't optimise the code for him, I answered the question. If I were OP I would change it from a string to a boolean, but maybe he has some crazy method that requires it to be a string.

Comment: No its `values['fileDir'] = $("#fileDir").val();` but it looks like my validtaion is not working